# Lua math.floor return wrong value

Tags: lua, floating-point, precision

.There is my code:

```
for k,v in pairs(result) do
  result[k] = math.floor(v*1000)/1000
  if k == 215 then
     print(v, math.floor(v*1000))
  end
end
for k,v in pairs(extra) do
  extra[k] = math.floor(v*1000)/1000
end
```

Where

```
result[215] = 113
```

But when I run it by C++ Lua-Tinker, I get the print:

```
113, 112999
```

It's very confusing!

Comment: Your `result[215]` equals to `112.99999999999`, not `113`.  How did you obtain that "113-like" value?

Comment: result[215] = A * (1 + per), where A = 100 and per = 0.13 .  And I have print the A and per, which showed 100, 0.13.  And furthermore, "print(v, math.floor(v*1000))" shows 113,112999, why the value of v isn't 113?

Comment: `0.13` is not representable exactly as binary floating point number, so `per` equals to `0.129999999999` instead. But Lua standard function `print()` rounds a number to 14 digits before displaying it.

Comment: Thanks, I get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Egor Skriptunoff, I got the answer.
There is an exmple:

```
local num1 = 100 + 1300/100
print(num1, math.floor(num1))

local num2 = (1 + 13/100) * 100
print(num2, math.floor(num2))
```

And the result is:

```
113 113
113 112
```

Actually, the num2 = 112.9999999999999..., because of the `13/100`.But when use 'print' to show it, there is a round action:

```
local a=112.99999999999 --(the count of 9 is 11)
print(a)
local b=112.999999999999 --(the count of 9 is 12)
print(b)
```

the result is:

```
112.99999999999
113
```